# How to update bright value in css filter using javascript without removing other filter attributes.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, filter

I am trying to apply css filter effects using javascript `selectedItem.style.filter`.
While applying filter attribute `brightness`, another attribute `contrast` gets removed.

#### Below is the code:

```
$('.brightness').on('input', function(){
  var bright = $('.brightness').val();
  var selectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
  selectedItem.style.filter = "brightness("+bright+"%)";
});

$('.contrast').on('input', function(){
  var contrast = $('.contrast').val();
  var selectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
  selectedItem.style.filter = "contrast("+contrast+"%)";
});
```

If i modify the code like below, i can get only one attribute(bright or contrast) on input, then how can i can update **only brightness without contrast** ?

```
selectedItem.style.filter = "brightness("+bright+"%) contrast("+contrast+"%)";
```

Sample code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/vs2msc3L/3/).

Note: I am using javascript code `selectedItem.style.filter` within reactjs to update filter value.
Thats why i need code in javascript, not in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to combine both values in a single event. Simply add `.slider` class to both sliders.

```
$('.slider').on('input', function () {
    var bright = $('.brightness').val();
    var contrast = $('.contrast').val();

    var selectedItem = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
    selectedItem.style.filter = "contrast("+contrast+"%) " + "brightness("+bright+"%)";
});
```

This works with both brightness and contrast.